# Including several files inside while loop in php

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

i currently have a cronjob, that calls a php file every five minutes.
Within this file there is a mysqli query that gets a list of file names which are then included in the while loop.
The files are for an autoposter for facebook.
All of that works great but the issue is, that everytime a file has an issue and an error occurs the entire while loop stops working.

Question: Is there a way for me to fire those files without having to include them within the while loop?

Comment: Inside the loop, perform error handling. If the error is then call the function "continue"

Comment: Do you mean with try catch?

Comment: yes, try catch.